# PyGTK cannot find my python 2.7 folder on Windows

Tags: python, windows, 64-bit, pygtk

I am trying to install Python 2.7 PyGTK 2.24.2 on a 64 bit win 7 PC. My python is 2.7.1 [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)].

I downloaded pygtk-all-in-one-2.24.2.win32-py2.7.msi from the PyGTK website, but when running it, there is a popup window: "Python 2.7 could not be located on your system." And the installation failed.

Is it because my python is for x64? Or, do I have to setup any environment variable (which I already did for PYTHONPATH)?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it's because your Python is 64 bit and pygtk is 32 bit. Install 32 bit Python (in a separate directory) or use a 64 bit build of pygtk, e.g. from <http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygtk>